# Javascript Alertify

Tags: javascript, alertify

I have an htm table, the positions, and questions for them, for user answer

```
<table id="position_holder">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>СБ</td>
            <td>
            <a id="6" href="/position-holder/#">Руководитель службы СБ</a>
                <div class="question">Имеете ли вы высшее образование?</div>
                <div class="question">Ваш стаж работы по специальности не менее 5 лет в правоохранительных органах ?</div>
                <div class="question">Ваш возраст от 25 до 50 лет?</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Отдел безопасности объектов СБ</td>
            <td>
            <a id="7" href="/position-holder/#">Начальник отдела</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ДБиОТ, ООС и ОЗ</td>
            <td>
            <a id="8" href="/position-holder/#">Директор ДБиОТ, ООС и ОЗ</a>
            <div class="question">Ваш возраст от 25 до 50 лет?</div>
                <div class="question">Ваш стаж работы по специальности не менее 5 лет (в нефтяной промышленности на руководящих должностях)?</div>
                <div class="question">Ваш стаж работы в текущей должности не менее 2 лет?</div>
                <div class="question">Есть ли у Вас в наличии высшее профессиональное (техническое)образование?</div>
                <div class="question">Ваша текущая должность в АО "КБМ", согласно оргструктуре, находится на одну ступень ниже либо является аналогичной в другом подразделении?</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ДБиОТ, ООС и ОЗ</td>
            <td>
            <a id="9" href="/position-holder/#">Ведущий специалист гражданской обороны</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i have a javascript. If user click on position he have to test pass with questions in there.

```
$('#position_holder td a').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).next().text() == ''){
        alertify.alert('Tests are not set!');
    }
    $(this).parents("td").find(".question").each(function (index) {
       if(!confirm($(this).text())){
           alertify.alert('Test faild!');
           return false;
        }else if($(this).next().text() == ''){
           console.log('Test success! Ajax request started!');
           alertify.alert('Test passed!');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

It works well. I need to have some buity to confirm and alert messages.

I use a http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/ library to it.

Alerts looks well, but i cant figure how to implement it it confirm.

I cant set `if(!alerify.confirm($(this).text())){` it not working, and even to do it throw loop, please help!

Comment: Have you read how to use alertify.confirm - https://github.com/fabien-d/alertify.js/wiki/How-to-Use

Comment: yes i tryed to use  alertify.confirm( message, function (e) {
    if (e) {
        //after clicking OK
    } else {
        //after clicking Cancel
    }
});

Comment: But it not works as i expected in the loop, so i need to guide me, or to give a direction use another library that can not confirm !confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i do it myself

```
        $('#position_holder td a').on('click', function(){
            if($(this).next().text() == ''){
                alertify.alert('No test here yet!');
                return false;
            }
            var questions = $(this).parents("td").find(".question").toArray();
            var posId = $(this).attr('id');
            answerTheQuestion(questions, questions.length, 0, posId);
            return false;
        });

        function answerTheQuestion(questions, num, pos, posId){
            if(num == 0){
                alertify.alert('Test done!');
                return false;
            }
            console.log(questions, num, pos, posId);
            var currentQuestion = questions[pos];
            alertify.confirm($(currentQuestion).text(), function (e) {
                if (e) {
                    // user clicked "ok"
                    answerTheQuestion(questions, num - 1, pos + 1, posId);
                } else {
                    // user clicked "cancel"
                    alertify.alert('Test failed!');
                }
            });
        }
```